# Rails 4 where clause on nested joined tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

currently I have this query:

```
Mother.joins(camp: [{ sub_center: [{ health_center: :block }] }])
```

which essentially joins the `mother` table to the `block` table through the `camp`, `sub_center`, and `health_center` tables (I know it's a lot to take). I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Mother.joins(camp: [{ sub_center: [{ health_center: :block }] }]).where(sub_center_id: 1)
```

However, I get that `sub_center_id` is an undefined column `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column mothers.sub_center_id does not exist`

How do I get it to query `camp.sub_center_id` instead of `mother.sub_center_id`? In other words, how do I execute a where clause on nested joined tables?

Here's the schema for given tables:

```
create_table "mothers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "camp_id"
    t.integer  "eligible_couple_id"
    t.string   "pcts_id"
    t.integer  "thumb_id"
    t.string   "survey_id"
    t.string   "necklace_id"
    t.integer  "necklace_replacement_number", default: 0
    t.boolean  "facility_referral_true",      default: false
    t.float    "weight_at_las_pnc"
    t.integer  "created_by"
    t.integer  "updated_by"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                  null: false
    t.string   "reg_id"
    t.string   "nfc_data"
    t.datetime "date_of_registration"
    t.integer  "status",                      default: 1,     null: false
    t.datetime "deleted_at"
    t.datetime "completed_at"
  end

create_table "camps", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "english_name"
    t.string   "local_name"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "created_by"
    t.integer  "updated_by"
    t.integer  "sub_center_id"
    t.integer  "week_of_the_month"
    t.integer  "status",            default: 1
    t.integer  "day"
    t.datetime "deleted_at"
  end

  create_table "health_centers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "block_id"
    t.string   "english_name"
    t.string   "local_name"
    t.boolean  "phc_true",         default: false
    t.boolean  "ipd_true",         default: false
    t.boolean  "fru_true",         default: false
    t.boolean  "always_open_true", default: false
    t.string   "phone_number"
    t.integer  "created_by"
    t.integer  "updated_by"
    t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
    t.integer  "status",           default: 1
    t.datetime "deleted_at"
  end

create_table "sub_centers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "health_center_id"
    t.string   "english_name"
    t.string   "local_name"
    t.boolean  "phc_true",         default: false
    t.boolean  "ipd_true",         default: false
    t.boolean  "fru_true",         default: false
    t.boolean  "always_open_true", default: false
    t.string   "phone_number"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.integer  "created_by"
    t.integer  "updated_by"
    t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
    t.integer  "status",           default: 1
    t.datetime "deleted_at"
  end

  create_table "blocks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "english_name"
    t.string   "local_name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "created_by"
    t.integer  "updated_by"
    t.integer  "status",       default: 1
    t.datetime "deleted_at"
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the string method to reference the column, instead of the symbol one.

```
Mother.
  joins(camp: { sub_center: { health_center: :block } }).
  where('camps.sub_center_id = ?', 1)
```

or with the symbol method

```
Mother.
  joins(camp: { sub_center: { health_center: :block } }).
  where(camps: { sub_center_id: 1 } )
```